# How do I revover a btrfs filesystem that will not mount (but mount returns without error), checks ok, errors out on restore?

Tags: btrfs

SYNOPSIS

## mount -o degraded,ro /dev/disk/by-uuid/ec3  /mnt/ec3/ && echo noerror

noerror

DESCRIPTION
mount -t btrfs fails but returns with noerror as above and only since the last reboot.
btrfs check seems clean to me (I am simple user).
btrfs restore errors out with  "We have looped trying to restore files in"...
I had a lingering artifact btrfs filesystem show  giving "        *** Some devices missing  " on the volume.  This meant it would not automount on boot and I have been manually mounting (+ searching for a resolution to that)
I have previously used rdfind to deduplicate with hard links (as many as 10 per file)
I had just backed up using btrfs send/recieve but have to check if I have everything - this was the main Raid1 server

DETAILS

## btrfs-find-root /dev/disk/by-uuid/ec3

Superblock thinks the generation is 103093
Superblock thinks the level is 1
Found tree root at 8049335181312 gen 103093 level 1

## btrfs restore -Ds /dev/disk/by-uuid/ec3 restore_ec3

We have looped trying to restore files in

## df -h /mnt/ec3/

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0        16G   16G  483M  97% /

## mount -o degraded,ro /dev/disk/by-uuid/ec3  /mnt/ec3/ && echo noerror

noerror

## df /mnt/ec3/

Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0       16775168 15858996    493956  97% /

## btrfs filesystem show /dev/disk/by-uuid/ec3

Label: none  uuid: ec3
        Total devices 3 FS bytes used 1.94TiB
        devid    6 size 2.46TiB used 1.98TiB path /dev/mapper/26d2e367-65ea-47ad-b298-d5c495a33efe
        devid    7 size 2.46TiB used 1.98TiB path /dev/mapper/3c193018-5956-4637-9ec2-dd5e49a4a412
        *** Some devices missing  #### comment, this is an old artifact unchanged since before unable to mount

## btrfs check /dev/disk/by-uuid/ec3

Checking filesystem on /dev/disk/by-uuid/ec3
UUID: ec3
checking extents
checking free space cache
checking fs roots
checking csums
checking root refs
found 2132966506496 bytes used err is 0
total csum bytes: 2077127248
total tree bytes: 5988204544
total fs tree bytes: 3492638720
total extent tree bytes: 242151424
btree space waste bytes: 984865976
file data blocks allocated: 3685012271104
 referenced 3658835013632
btrfs-progs v4.1.2

Update:
After a reboot (had to wait for a slot to go down) the system mounts manually but not completely clean.

Now asking question on irc #btrfs:

## ! http://pastebin.com/359EtZQX

Hi, I'm scratching my head and searched in vain to remove *** Some devices missing.  Can anyone help give me a clue to clean this up?
- is there a good way to 'fix' the artifacts I am seeing? trying: scrub, balance.  Try: resize, defragment.
- would I be advised to move to a new clean volume set?
- would a fix via a btrfs send/recieve be safe from propogating errors?
- or (more painfully) rsync to a clean volume?   http://pastebin.com/359EtZQX   (My first ever day using irc)

Comment: Did you manage to recover it? I'm curious if btrfs send/receive propogated any errors... Also, what was the last thing you did before it died?